# How can I fix this adb installation failure?

Tags: android, installation, adb

[image]

```
adb: failed to install dc.apk: Failure [-116]
```

I'm trying to install an apk via adb on my phone but it doesn't work.
What does that failure message mean and how can i fix it?

restarting my phone did nothing to it

Comment: It is very unusual that adb install does not print an human readable error message. Please check the APK file using an ZIP tool and make sure, reboot the Android device and make sure it has enough free storage. Which adb version do you use?

Comment: Run `adb --version` and show the output

Comment: It says Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 30.0.5-6877874
Installed as C:\adb\adb.exe